# Only print last value in definite loop

Tags: python, loops

How to print last value in definite range?

```
def main():
 print "This program calculates the future value of a 10-year investment."

 principal = input("Enter the initial principle: ")
 apr = input("Enter the annual interest rate: ")

 for i in range(10):
  principal = principal * (1 + apr)
  print "The value in 10 years is:", principal
```

OUTPUT:

```
The value in 10 years is XXXXXXX
The value in 10 years is XXXXXXX
The value in 10 years is XXXXXXX
The value in 10 years is XXXXXXX
The value in 10 years is XXXXXXX
The value in 10 years is XXXXXXX
The value in 10 years is XXXXXXX
The value in 10 years is XXXXXXX
The value in 10 years is XXXXXXX
The value in 10 years is XXXXXXX
```

How do I print just the last iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 6):

Unindent the last line (and please don't use 1 space indenting ever again, [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends 4 spaces)

```
def main():
    print "This program calculates the future value of a 10-year investment."

    principal = input("Enter the initial principle: ")
    apr = input("Enter the annual interest rate: ")

    for i in range(10):
        principal = principal * (1 + apr)
    print "The value in 10 years is:", principal
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move the `print` line out of the `for`-loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    principal = principal * (1 + apr)
print "The value in 10 years is:", principal
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    print "This program calculates the future value of a 10-year investment."
    principal = input("Enter the initial principle: ")
    apr = input("Enter the annual interest rate: ")
    for i in range(10):
        principal *= (1 + apr)
        print "The value in {0} years is: {1}".format(i + 1, principal)
```

If you're really only interested in the 10-year value, replace the for loop by

```
print "The value in 10 years is:", principal * (1 + apr) ** 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    with open("story.txt",encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split()
                aList.append( word )
        print(aList)
```

Comment: Moved the print statement out of the for loop and it only prints the last value of the for loop